# How to install ios App debuggable on my Iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa, ios-provisioning

Prerequisite I have

- I Registered an Developer Account
- I have a Development Certificate
- I have a Development Provisioning Profile

But I really don't get it how to export my app with this "Development" stuff to an .ipa file OR install it on my Iphone. If I click run I can debug it. But I want to install it also.

If I click *"Product > Archive"* it open the Organizer, there I can click Export and have 3 options "for IOS App Store", "Ad Hoc" and "Enterprise"

but I read everywhere that you can't debug with "Ad Hoc" and "Enterprise" and I don't want to put it in App Store. So there is no option "for development".

So I really have no idea of how to export this for development.. Any Ideas?

Comment: what you are actually want to do? Need to test your app after installation in your device?

Comment: So you want to install it on other devices? What do you mean with "for development"? So on other devices to test the app?

Comment: Select your device in Xcode and use Cmd-R to build and run on the device.

Comment: but how can i make a .ipa file @derdida yes for other devices which i also inlcuded as devices with the udid.

Comment: same like creating ipa using adhoc profile. Product->Archive->Export-->save for adhoc deployment